# Gears playing up after a chain replacement

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, gears

I had used my bike for about a year and thought it was about time to replace the chain. The old chain started to skip links, but only sometimes. 
I got the right chain from my local bike shop, I sized it up using my old chain, so it should have been the right length. 
I put it on, however, now I got problems with shifting my gears (especially to lighter gears). Before the  chain replacement I didn't have problems with shifting between the gears. 
It also sometimes skips links. 
Does anyone know what might be the problem?
Thanks,
K

Comment: Did you change your cassette?   If not - how worn is it ?